# How to emit data for specific group of peoples in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a user with multiple friends. If that user send some data i just want that data is only emit to the friends. Like in Facebook i have a multiple user and i am emitting data only to the friends. Thank you

Comment: Rooms do this https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#Default-room

Comment: I have tried rooms but i am not understanding how to subscribe for multiple friends

Comment: Is this a chat feature or a posts and likewise feature

Comment: Its like i showing online list when user comes online. i just want to show user friends about status online or offline